# OOP design for a data processing pipeline

Tags: oop, dataframe, statistics

I have a collection of instances of the same object, like so (in Python - my question is actually language independent)

```
class shopping_cart:
    def __init__(self, newID, newproduct, currentdate, dollars ):
        shopping_cart.customerID = newID
        shopping_cart.product = newproduct
        shopping_cart.date = currentdate
        shopping_cart.value = dollars
```

that models what each customer bought, when, and for how much money. Now, in the software that I'm writing I need to compute some basic statistics about my customers and for this I need to compute things like the mean value of all items that were bought - or the mean value each single customer bought. Currently the dataset is very small, so I do this by looping over all instances of my `shopping_cart` objects and extracting the data from each instance as I need it.

But data will get huge soon enough - and then it might be that looping like that is simply too slow to get everyday statistics in time - and for different operations I will need my data to be organized in structures that will offer speed for the range of operations that I want to perform in the future (e.g. vectorized data, so that I can make use of fast algorithms for that).

Is there a way to use OOP design that sufficiently well allows me to refactor the underlying data structures by separating the operations that I need to perform on the data from the structure in which the data is saved? (I might have to rewrite my code and redesign my class, but I'd rather do it now, to support such encapsulation, than do it later, where I might have to go through much bigger refactoring when I have to rewrite the operations *and* the data structures together.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question mixes two different things.

One is decoupling your objects from the methods you want to apply to them. You will be interested in the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern for that.

The other is about increasing performance when processing lots of objects. For this you can consider the [Pipe and Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipes_and_filters) (or Pipeline) pattern where you partition the objects to process them in parallel execution pipelines and group results in the end.

As a footnote I think you meant

```
class shopping_cart:
    def __init__(self, newID, newproduct, currentdate, dollars ):
        self.customerID = newID
        self.product = newproduct
        self.date = currentdate
        self.value = dollars
```

Otherwise you are setting class members, not instance members.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot for pointing me to the Visitor pattern, it looks very promising for the problem I have! And you were right about my code :-s

Comment: @l7ll7, you are welcome, glad to help. As a final advice, a reasonable understanding of both OOP and the language you are using is recommended before using patterns with them (but another point of view is that you should research patterns when you feel that you face a problem that shouldn't be new).